# Getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []: Trigger

Tags: trigger

This Error am getting while editing the Task. For first time it is saved i,e. Insertion. but after insert am trying to edit, The above error is occurring. I have checked the object permissions for logged in profile user, it has full permissions and OWD is private. The strange thing is even from system admin user also can't able to edit the Task. What could be the issue, can any one help me

Comment: Check for a hard coded value inside a trigger related to your operation

Comment: Since OWD is private, please check the access for WhoId and WhatId of the task. You may miss the access for anyone of these 2.